# How to use only the luminosity of the environment texture but without color influence?

Tags: node-editor, color

Sometimes, environment textures are good to give a more realistic look to the rendering.

But, it may be hard to tune the colors because of it :

- Blue sky visible on the top right part (from the environment texture)
- Greeny sand (which is normally more yellow) on the bottom part

[image]

Is it possible to have the lighting only on the mesh objects (no color influence, only the light strength), but keeping the colors in the background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this setup will work. It desaturates the image that will light the scene, but the original image will be visible to the camera.

[image]

A different version suggested by JtheNinja. I also needed substract node to switch 0 and 1, and multiply node to control the strength of light.

[image]

Comment: thanks. It is not self evident for me to use HSV instead of B&W. Could you explain a bit more ?

Comment: if you set saturation channel to 0 image will appear grayscale.

Comment: If you attach "is camera ray" to the "fac" input on the HSV node you can get away with removing the mix and only having 1 background shader instead of 2. This is very slightly more efficient to render.

Comment: @JtheNinja thanks, I created a new version and updated the answer, however I needed additional nodes. Maybe this shall be done some other way?